# Correct Pattern for Postgres DB Connection

Tags: c#, .net-core, aws-lambda, dependency-injection

I have an AWS Lambda Function that is connecting to a Postgres DB.

The issue is then token to connect is expiring after 15 mins and then cannot be used.  I am wondering is it something with how I have wired up my Services.

This is my DBConext class:

```
    public NpgsqlConnection DBConnection { get; }

    public DatabaseContext()
    {
        DBConnection = new NpgsqlConnection(GetConnectionString());
    }

    private string GetConnectionString()
    {
        var token = RDSAuthTokenGenerator.GenerateAuthToken(_databaseEndpoint, _databasePort, _databaseUsername);
        Console.WriteLine("Token Generated: " + token);
        //further code removed for Brevity
```

In Startup my DBContext is wired up as Transient:

```
services.AddTransient<DatabaseContext>();
```

Then in the Service making a call to the DB I have the following:

```
    protected readonly DatabaseContext _db;

    public MyDbService(DatabaseContext db)
    {
        _db = db;
    }

    public async Task<long> GetUserDetails(string userId)
    {
        try
        {
            NpgsqlConnection _connection = await DBConnectService.OpenDBConnection(_db.DBConnection);
            //further code removed for Brevity
```

This Db Service is wired up as scoped:

```
    services.AddScoped<IMyDbService, MyDbService>();
```

The code works and runs and I can call the API and return the details.  But my Debug Line Token Generated only gets call on initial run once.  And then after 15 mins the token expires and then my API fails as it cannot connect to the DB.

Is the wiring up of these services done incorrectly?

I was wondering perhaps I should not be 'newing' up the DB connection in the DatabaseContext constructor

My DatabaseContext class does implement IDisposable and has the methods:

```
    ~DatabaseContext()
    {
        Dispose(false);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposed)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (disposing)
        {
            // Dispose managed objects
            if (DBConnection.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open) DBConnection.Close();
            DBConnection.Dispose();
        }
        // Dispose unmanaged objects
        disposed = true;
    }
```

This is my DbConnectService class also:

```
public static class DBConnectService
{
    public static async Task<NpgsqlConnection> OpenDBConnection(NpgsqlConnection connection)
    {
        var _connection = connection;
        if (_connection.State != System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
            await _connection.OpenAsync();
        return _connection;
    }
}
```

Comment: you need to dispose the connection when done - look how to implement `IDisposable`

Comment: my DB context does implement IDisposable and I have the Dispose methods implemented - ill update the question details for clarity